# How to combine multiple colums in a MYSQL Query that uses COUNT and WHERE

Tags: mysql

So I have figured out how to generate a report that will count items for each month based upon a WHERE criteria like:

```
  SELECT
  Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`)) as YEAR,
  Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`)) as MONTH,
  Count(*) As BUY_RESULT 
  FROM zupsbackup
  WHERE Result='BUY' AND tPeriod='60' 
  GROUP BY Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`)), Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`))
```

This produces table result like

```
YEAR|MONTH|BUY_RESULT
```

However my Result column has 2 possible values BUY and SELL.

So I want to add another column to the result so that it looks like

```
YEAR|MONTH|BUY_RESULT|SELL_RESULT
```

How can I create another column in MYSQL ???

I have tried UNION but this adds the SELL results to the end of the results table and does not create the extra column.

So how do I create an extra column using a WHERE clause so that RESULT='SELL' to be added next to the existing column where RESULT='BUY' ?????

Thanks !!!!!

Comment: Maybe IF - THAN, take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`)) as YEAR, Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`)) as MONTH,
       SUM(Result = 'BUY') As BUY_RESULT, SUM(Result = 'SELL') as SELL_RESULT
FROM zupsbackup
WHERE tPeriod = '60' 
GROUP BY Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`)), Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tTime1`));
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to accomplish this is to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT 
  Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(tTime1)) as YEAR, 
  Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(tTime1)) as MONTH, 
  Count(*) As BUY_RESULT, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(sub.*) 
    FROM 
      zupsbackup AS sub 
    WHERE 
      sub.Result = 'SELL' and 
      sub.tPeriod = '60' AND 
      Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(sub.tTime1)) = YEAR AND 
      Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(tTime1)) = MONTH
  ) AS SELL_RESULT
FROM 
  zupsbackup 
WHERE 
  Result='BUY' AND 
  tPeriod='60' 
GROUP BY 
  Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(tTime1)), 
  Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(tTime1))
```